# How to setup Postgres RLS for a web application

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

I am new to Postgres and I am trying to understand how to set up RLS policies for a public facing web site with many thousands of users.  I have a UserSessions table in which a row needs to be inserted each time a user logs into the site.  Only the db admin and site admin should be able view this data from the same web site that the public uses.

Additionally, there are user specific tables that allow individual site users to set up alerts.  These users should only be able to insert, update, delete and view their own alerts.

How do I set up RLS so the website can insert a record into the UserSessions table, only the two admins can view the user sessions from the website, and the individual users can only CRUD only their alerts records from the website?  It seems to me that I should be doing something like creating a role for the website that has all of the policies attached but I am unclear on how to do something like that and how those policy permissions are passed to postgres.

I'm looking for advice on how to set up RLS policies for a website for these scenarios.

Thanks!

Comment: row-level-security as in mssql security is not available in the most current version of Postgres, however it may be on the radar.

Comment: Usually you'd do that kind of filtering with simple `WHERE` clauses as part of your app?! It's not like every user of your app has an individual user account to connect to the database with, no? It's your app having a single user account to connect to the database, and then it decides which data to get from it and present to the user. There are scenarios where the app or different parts of it may have different accounts with different permissions, but that's a more specialised scenario and not the baseline.

Comment: @RossBush Could you please elaborate on the differences between SQL Server and PostgreSQL when it comes to their RLS implementations? Because “not available” is just not true

Comment: @FrankHeikens - You are correct, this feature was released last week in a RC. The last time I inquired, it was not supported. [ 31st August 2023 PostgreSQL 16 RC1 Released] - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html

Comment: @RossBush Last week? You mean 9 years ago. RLS is available since version 9.5, released in January 2016. Bullet number 3: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/release-9-5.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens - So it is a big misunderstanding on my part. Our team was asking AWS if Aurora Postgres supported row level security based on the user account making the connection and was told that could be supported in future release. I mistakenly took this to mean rls was not supported. That may be only a difference, however, I took it to mean it was not supported. I stand corrected and thank you for the information.

Comment: @deceze - thank you for your comment.  Coming from sql server, a simple WHERE clause is used.  Being new to Postgres I was trying to wrap my head around how RLS would apply to such a scenario outside of creating a role/policy for each user which seemed rather impractical.